# Invalid character replace with white space

Tags: php, zend-framework, replace

I'm currently trying to filter alphanumeric characters only. Therefore, I've tried a following Zend Function,

```
$filter = new Zend_Filter_Alnum(array('allowwhitespace' => true));
$return = $filter->filter('This is (my) content: 123');
```

This actually amazing but the issue is here I need to replaced the characters with white space. For example if I enter "Hel#o wor*d" it has to be "Hel o wor d". Aslo I've tried php str_replace function it's actually good but I've to define there a loads of invalid characters. Could any please tell me how to do this easily ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can create a custom filter for that   [Writing Custom Filters](http://framework.zend.com/manual/1.12/en/zend.filter.writing_filters.html)

** For your requirement copy the Zend Alphanumeric fiter (Zend_Filter_Alnum) and replace `preg_replace($pattern, '', (string) $value);` (line 144) to
`preg_replace($pattern, ' ', (string) $value);`

Answer (score 2):

you can do it via using `preg_replace()`  function

```
<?php 
  $someone = "Hel#o wor*d";
  echo  preg_replace('/[\s\W]+/',' ',$someone); 
 ?>
```

Output -

```
Hel o wor d
```